# Generating Secure (https) URLs from AppEngine ImagesService

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Google's AppEngine ImagesService by default returns non-secure (http) URLs for images.  It would be good if it had a methoed that would generate secure (https) URLs.  For example, `getServingUrl` could be complemented by `getSecureServingUrl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getServingUrl method already allows you to specify "secure" in ServingUrlOptions.

Answer (score 0):

A (less then adequate) workaround is to simply replace `http://` with `https://` in the URL.  This works, but since it is undocumented, it could presumably stop working at any time.  For example:

```
url.replaceAll("^http:", "https:")
```

would work.